# DateTime Conversion format in Linq to XML

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, linq-to-xml

**I am using the following query:**
[image]
 **I am getting the following Output.**

[image]

**How can I get Date field without of "T" ?**

```
[Table(Name = "MT_PHARMACY_INV_COUNT")]
    public class PharmacyInvCount
    {      
        [Column]
        public string DEVICE_ID { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string CREATE_USER_NAME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string UPDATE_USER_NAME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime? ENTRY_DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime CREATE_DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime? UPDATE_DATE_TIME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime? START_DT_TIME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public DateTime? END_DT_TIME { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string COMMENTS { get; set; }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to achieve that by manually converting your `DateTime` data to `string` with specific format, for example :

```
............
//example output format : 2014-03-19
new XElement("ENTRY_DATE_TIME", pic.ENTRY_DATE_TIME.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
//example output format : 2014-03-19 13:20:56
new XElement("ENTRY_DATE_TIME", pic.ENTRY_DATE_TIME.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")),
............
```